# C++ - Returning an array to main function and passing array to another function

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm having trouble with returning an array from a function to the main function. The array is also used as a parameter for another function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

void ran(int list[]);
void guess(int list[]);
int black_marker(int num1[], int num2[]);

int main(){
    int r[4];
    int g[4];
    cout << black_marker(ran(r), guess(g));
}

void ran(int list[]){       //random number generator
    srand (time(NULL));
    int a = rand() % 6 + 1;
    int b = rand() % 7 + 1;
    while(a == b)
        b = rand() % 7 + 1;
    int c = rand() % 8 + 1;
    while(a == c || b == c)
        c = rand() % 8 + 1;
    int d = rand() % 9 + 1;
    while(a == d || b == d || c == d)
        d = rand() % 9 + 1;

    int num_random[4] = {a, b, c, d};
}

void guess(int list[]){         //takes user input for a guess
    int random_no[4];
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        cin >> random_no[i];
    }
}

int black_marker(int num1[], int num2[]){   //Counts how many digits from random number
    int black_count = 0;                    //is similar to the user's guess
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        if(num1[i] == num2[i]){
            black_count += 1;
        }
    }
    return black_count;
}
```

Basically, this is an incomplete number-guessing game where the user is given a hint such as the number of digits that are common to the randomly generated number and the user input guess. I get a void type error for `cout << black_marker(ran(r), guess(g));` which is unusual since this pass-by-reference method works otherwise when I have a cout statement in the void function's body.

Comment: Welcome to C++ and all the nice containers built-in as part of its standard library. Use a `std::vector<int>`. And read up on *passing by constant reference*.

Comment: black_marker takes as first argument array but you supply a void function void ran(r)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`black_marker(ran(r), guess(g))`  `black_marker` takes two arrays, but `ran()` and `guess(g)` return void, so you end up with `black_marker(void, void)` and that won't work.

What you wanna do is

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void ran(int list[]){       //random number generator
    srand (time(NULL));
    int a = rand() % 6 + 1;
    int b = rand() % 7 + 1;
    while(a == b)
        b = rand() % 7 + 1;
    int c = rand() % 8 + 1;
    while(a == c || b == c)
        c = rand() % 8 + 1;
    int d = rand() % 9 + 1;
    while(a == d || b == d || c == d)
        d = rand() % 9 + 1;

    list[0] = a;
    list[1] = b;
    list[2] = c;
    list[3] = d;
}

void guess(int list[]){         //takes user input for a guess
    int random_no[4];
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        cin >> list[i];
    }
}
int black_marker(int num1[], int num2[]){   //Counts how many digits from random number
    int black_count = 0;                    //is similar to the user's guess
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        if(num1[i] == num2[i]){
            black_count += 1;
        }
    }
    return black_count;
}
int main(){
    int r[4];
    int g[4];
    ran(r);
    guess(g);
    cout << black_marker(r, g) << endl;
}
```

however you should drop the C-style arrays and use `std::vector` or `std::array` instead.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that `std::vector` was more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

When you use

```
black_marker(ran(r), guess(g))
```

`black_marker` is called by using the return values of `ran(r)` and `guess(g)`. The return types of those functions are `void`. The argument types to `black_marker` are declared to be `int []`. That's the argument type mismatch the compiler is complaining about.

Use

```
ran(r);
guess(g);
cout << black_marker(r, g);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick note:

Your function

```
int black_marker(int num1[], int num2[]);
```

takes integer arrays (references) as input arguments however you provide them with void using the function call :

```
black_marker(ran(r), guess(g));
```

since ran(r) and guess(g) returns void (nothing) as Pablo pointed.

Sahu`s solution will work well.

Additionally, if you want to insist on the original function call:

```
black_marker(ran(r), guess(g));
```

Then you may return the int pointers from the functions "ran" and "guess" as follows:

```
int* ran(int list[]) { 
    ...
    return list;
}

int* guess(int list[]) {  
    ...
    return list;
}
```

then your function call would work fine since the size is known (=4).

Alternatively, you may use array references:

```
int ( &ran( int (&list)[4] ) )[4] { 
    return list;
}
```

and

```
int ( &guess( int (&list)[4] ) )[4] { 
    return list;
}
```